# Picopala algorithm implementation

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I have this recursive definition:

[image]

The first call to that function is `picopala(v.length-1, v)`, `v` is an array of integers.
I need to transform that definition to iterative algorithm but I can't, I don't know how I can make it. So, please, can anyone help me?

Comment: Recursion is the way to go.

Comment: Is there a reason you must not use recursion?  It will have the same time complexity as iterative code, and probably its running time just a small factor slower in practice, and it's almost trivial to code.

Comment: But if you must use iteration: The key is to look at which previous solutions are needed to calculate the current solution, then make sure that you always process them in order so that these dependencies are satisfied.  Here, picopala(j, V) only uses the results of picopala(j-1, V) and picopala(j-2, V) -- meaning that if you calculate the solutions in *increasing* order of j, all dependencies will be satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an iterative solution, let's "turn it around" and start working from zero up.

Let's store the values of `picopala(j, V)` in `P[j]`.

```
P[0] = V[0]
P[1] = 2*V[1]
P[2] = P[0] * P[1] + V[1]
P[3] = P[1] * P[2] + V[2]
P[4] = P[2] * P[3] + V[3]
...
P[n] = P[n-2] * P[n-1] + V[n-1]
```

Now it's easy to implement as a loop.

Comment: Actually, if working ground-up and values are not to be reused again and again, an array of 2 is enough too. In this case, after every calculation, the previous result is shifted to index 0, and current result is put into index 1. This way,

    {"new result" = [0] * [1] + V[n-1];
     shift [1] to [0];
     shift "new result" to [1]; }

becomes the new formula. Iterate this process until requested index.

Answer (score 0):

`Recursion` perfectly suits here.

Assuming you can use recursion,you an try something like this

```
public int picopala(int length,int[] arr)
    {
        //base conditions
        if(length == 0)
            return arr[0];
        if(length == 1)
            return arr[1]*2;

        return picopala(length-2,arr)*picopala(length-1,arr)+arr[length-1];

    }
```

Comment: I did in that way, but now I need to do it in iterative code because is homework. But thanks!

Comment: This has exponential time complexity, O(2^n), but O(n) is possible.

Comment: Recursion in such algorithms are easy to implement, but wasteful. Because at every iteration, you are recalculating the values you normally already did.